# VMWare Fusion access guest vm (windows) from host (mac)

Tags: macos, windows-8, vmware-fusion

I am needing to access the localhost of a guest windows 8 vm from my Mac OS (10.9) host.  The windows 8 vm is running in VMWare Fusion.  How can I do this?
I have tried getting the guest ip address with ipconfig, and then typing that IP address into the browser on my mac, but it won't connect, and i can't ping that ip address from the mac either.
I have tried doing this in both NAT and Bridged networking modes in VMWare Fusion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found what I needed to do here. To connect to localhost of the guest os firstly:

- make sure the network settings of the windows vm in vmware fusion are set to: NAT (Share with my mac)
- Turn off windows firewall for guest or public networks in windows 8 (just search for windows firewall and select "Turn Windows Firewall on or off")
- get the ip address of the windows vm by opening a command prompt and typing "ipconfig"

Once you have done these things, you should be able to switch to the mac os, and navigate the windows ip address in a web browser.

Comment: You don't have to turn the firewall off entirely if you don't want to; you can create an inbound rule in the firewall. E.g. for http access create a rule for port 80. The profile will need to be public.

Comment: Also working fine in bridged mode

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit of detail to Tyler's answer, where he wrote "make sure the network settings of the windows vm in vmware fusion are set to: NAT (Share with my mac)", in Fusion 5 you do this by going to Fusion's menu Virtual Machine --> Settings, click on Network Adapter, and select Share With My Mac.

Comment: That was not enough. Calling localhost didn't work from mac. Then I went to windows and looked at the IP address of the Ethernet0 adapter. That worked. I also added a firewall rule to allow the request to go through for the port I wanted.